# How to capture an output text value in variable in bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm running this command for getting the public IP of an EC2. It works as expected!

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=EC2" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text`

I'm trying to use this value for running this command, so instead of XX.XX.XX.XX it has to be the value I get from ec2 describe-instances 
`ansible-playbook provisioning/site.yml -i inventory --ssh-common-args '-o "proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p -i Key.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XX"'`

So I have my commands like this

```
IP=aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$NAME_PREFIX*" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text
export BASTION="ubuntu@${IP}"
ansible-playbook provisioning/site.yml -i inventory --ssh-common-args '-o "proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p -i Key.pem ${BASTION}"'
```

So not sure, how should I use that output, if you could help me please

Comment: Use: `IP=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=$NAME_PREFIX*" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to add `"Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"` clause in `filters` to make sure you get a running instance only so your `aws` command would be:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:Name,Values=$NAME_PREFIX*" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text
```

Now to store output IP in a variable, you can use command substitution:

```
ip=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:Name,Values=$NAME_PREFIX*" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text)
```

Then to use it:

```
export BASTION="ubuntu@$ip"
ansible-playbook provisioning/site.yml -i inventory --ssh-common-args '-o "proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p -i Key.pem '"$BASTION"'"'
```